# android-button background drawable doesn't work

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme

this is my xml drawbale code with the name of btntheme.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_normal_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_disabled_holo_light" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_pressed_holo_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_focused_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_normal_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_disabled_holo_light"/>

</selector>
```

I've put all those images with the these names in the drawable-hdpi folder .

this is my layout and the button :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="@drawable/btntheme"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_smallerButton" />
```

it's not working , it doesn't change the button theme at all ?

could you help me to solve it ?

thank you

Comment: try removing multiple states from item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out selector as below:

```
<!-- Active tab -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_normal_holo_light" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!-- Inactive tab -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_pressed_holo_light" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<!-- Pressed tab -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_pressed_holo_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/customactionbartheme_btn_default_disabled_holo_light" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

For more detail guidenc check out [Custom Selector in Android](http://www.abtosoftware.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-color-gradients-and-selectors-to-android-buttons-via-xml)

Answer (score 2):

try to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in xml file and xml file will like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected_focused" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected_pressed" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

after using this if it will not work then if possible try to use image view instead of button i think that will be work. thanks;-)

Answer (score 2):

navigate to `res/values/styles/styles.xml` or `res/values/themes/themes.xml`
and change `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

or just replace `MaterialComponents` with `AppCompat`

Comment: If you are using any Material components (e.g. com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton) in your application you need to use Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the screen you are testing on does not use drawable-hdpi, so try to move the images and xml file itself to the drawable folder, if it does not exist then create it.

Answer (score 1):

issue is with material design that is mentioned in style
simple replace it with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score -1):

Create **drawable** folder in **res** and put **btntheme.xml** in that folder .

Answer (score -1):

Ok I also suffered form this problem,
remove android:state_focused="true" line form your code and run.
hope get the answer :),
(i think focus is only for input type views in my knowledge if i wrong plz guide me)
for testing focus state press TAB  key
this is sample:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--When pressed-->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" />
    <!--focus state -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <!--Default State-->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent_black" />
<!-- how confirm focus state of button -->
</selector>
```