# What's making the button background white, shouldn't it be transparent?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

As you can see here, the background to the button is transparent. I can't seem to find where it's set to white in either xml files. The button is identified as `btnCapture` the code is below.

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCapture" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/capture"
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"


        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="202dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

rounded_button.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="#80000000"
    android:width="2dp"></stroke>
    <stroke android:color="#D3D3D3"></stroke>
    <size android:width="60dp"
        android:height="80dp"></size>
</shape>
```

Comment: The problem is not Java-related. Update the question with a snapshot of your `rounded_button.xml` file. That's where the problem is.

Comment: @Taslim Done. Still don't see where the issue is in that file though.

Comment: I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not change anything related to the UI of the button in your Java code, so no, it's not because of the Java code. It's XML related.

Your background of the button is a drawable named 'rounded_button', but you haven't posted the contents of that drawable file. So all we can do is guess that the rounded_button drawable is white?

Comment: Added the rounded_button.xml

Comment: You have 2x 'stroke' elements in the rounded_button.xml, and no 'solid' element. And neither of the colors in the XML are transparent.. Read it through and/or google 'android shape xml'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two quick steps you can take to make this work the exact way you desire:

**First**, change your view from a Button to a TextView and apply your `rounded-button.xml` background. This should work instantly. It's a bit tricky trying to set a background to a button as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624038/android-button-background-drawable-doesnt-work).

**Secondly**, I noticed that your `rounded-button.xml` file has no `solid` element. The solid element allows you to set the background of a layout. For this reason, I changed one of your `stroke` elements to a `solid` element (there shouldn't be two `stroke` elements anyway). Your updated `rounded_button.xml` code is as shown below:

**PS: Don't forget to change the view in your** `activity_main.xml` **from Button to TextView!**

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke android:color="#80000000"
        android:width="2dp">
    </stroke>

    <solid 
        android:color="#D3D3D3">
    </solid>

    <size 
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="80dp">
    </size>

</shape>
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: Hiya! Thanks for your try, I applied it. I changed it to TextView and changed the rounded_button.xml file to what you put yet still outputs the white box, the text is now outside the shape and the shape is oddly warped. As you can see here: https://prnt.sc/maqqpq

Comment: Add `android:gravity="center"` to your TextView xml to fix the position of the text. To eradicate the white color, change the background of your RelativeLayout to white.

Comment: If my suggestion above works, kindly mark this as the correct answer. ;-)

Comment: So, the reply definetly fixed the text outside of the area. That worked perfectly. Although I added the white background t o the RelativeLayout yet still get that white area around the button.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant you should change the background of the relative layout from white to any other color.